# pincode or zipcode not getting from geocode

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter, google-geocoder, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a flutter app. I want to print the pincode zip code of place. I am using geocoder library. The version is `geocoder 0.1.1` . I am trying the example shown library page https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder#-example-tab- 
The problem is pincode or zip code is not getting. It not coming. But the pincode is showing in address line.

```
    try{
        var geocoding = AppState.of(context).mode;
        var longitude = double.parse(_controllerLongitude.text);
        var latitude = double.parse(_controllerLatitude.text);
        var results = await geocoding.findAddressesFromCoordinates(new Coordinates(latitude, longitude));
        this.setState(() {
            this.results = results;
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        print("Error occured: $e");
    }
    finally {
        this.setState(() {
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

The `results[0].addressLine`will show address line with pincode. But `results[0].postalCode` showing null. 
How to solve the issue? Please help me? I am new to flutter.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmk1M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved after changing the version. I changed the version geocoder to 0.1.2.

https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_geocoder/issues/2#issuecomment-444282646